# netbeans missing native build tools

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, localhost, gdb

**My Goal**
I want to have a fully functioning NetBeans C/C++ on my ubuntu 18.04

**A small background**
The first problem I've encountered was

> build host not connected

after a little research I've discovered I need to manually install 
the compilers so I did the following:
Installing gcc, gpp, g++ and mingw using the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install <product_name>
```

**It had helped and I moved one step forward creating a C program and then pressing the build button only to encounter a second problem:**

**The Current Problem:**

> [netbeans missing native build tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaIIx.png)

**The steps I have taken so far:**

I knew I had to get MYSYS somehow (source: http://www.testerlogic.com/guide-configure-netbeans-ide-c/), 
but couldn't find out how on linux
so I did some more digging coming upon this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287380/setting-up-netbeans-for-c/2453750

That wasn't fully answered and the link to the NetBeans guide that was provided directs us to a broken link on the linux section..
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/67/cpp-setup-instructions.html
The Sun Studio 12 Compilers on Linux is broken.
[An apology message from Oracle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBBtY.png)

But is this really the problem? Do I need this Sun Studio 12 Compilers?
Or is there something else I should do it order to get this MYSYS part
that is required by NetBeans?

**Further Thought:**

How can I install only the relevant parts of the mingw using the terminal
and then install the complementary part of the MYSYS as required by NetBeans?

Or is there another way to fix this

> empty Make Command problem

?

**p.s.** I have the gdb installed as shown by the terminal upon
trying to install it `sudo apt-get install gdb`

*Thanks in advanced.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after asking a senior from my school we were able to fix the problem.

> **Using linux one does not need MINGW or MYSYS.**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

is what is needed and then from there if NetBeans doesn't figure where make is
just let it know that it's in usr/bin/make (there's a browse button next to 'Make Command' in the Build section).

DONE! :)